# System.InvalidOperationException: "Incorrect Content-Type"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

На одном компьютере всё работает. Перенёс на другой и студия пишет в том месте, где принимаю POST параметры - `System.InvalidOperationException: "Incorrect Content-Type`
Я в jquery менял всевозможные Content-Type, всёравно- пишет  Incorrect Content-Type и указанный тип.  Что-то вообще- не понял- чего на одном компе работает, а на другом ругается.
В чём может быть дело?

Comment: кода хоть немного то будет в вопросе? Вы `content-type` меняли в jquery как [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33711629/1216425) или как-то еще?

Comment: Дополните вопрос кодом, в котором падает ислючение, желательно и место вызова тоже показать. Просто не совсем понятно что да как.

Answer (score 0):

В Jquery ajax запросе добавил

```
$.ajax({
url: '/api/param1',
headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}....
```

и стало работать.